# Get recently updated results from Database when joining multiple tables using JPA in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring and JPA and I am trying to write a job in Spring which runs every 3 hours and retrieve the records from Oracle Database.

I would like to only read the new/updated content from the past 3 hours (ideally from the last job run).

I have seen few examples in https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/ where we can create queries and retrieve the data based on our requirements, but in my current use case, I am not using queries instead using the java classes with the annotations and using Join columns between different tables. There are chances that only one of the sub table is updated or all the tables are updated with new content. I need to get the results if at least one of the table is updated/inserted with new content.

Campus is the main table and retrieves the data from Group and Region, I need to fetch the data if any new data is updated in Campus table or even any group/region is added/modified.

I am using JDK7 as of now.

Is there a way to accomplish the above requirement?

Below are the sample Java classes for reference.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
@Table(name = "TABLE_CAMPUS")
public class Campus implements Auditable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SIMPLE_ID", sequenceName = "SIMPLE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SIMPLE_ID", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "CAMPUS_NAME")
    private String campusName;
    @Column(name = "CAMPUS_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long campusId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private GroupType groupType;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REGION_ID")
    private Region region;
    ....
    ...
}
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
@Table(name = "TABLE_GROUP_TYPE")
public class GroupType implements Auditable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "GROUP_TYPE_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "GROUP_TYPE_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "GROUP_TYPE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "GROUP_TYPE_SEQUENCE", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    @Column(name = "GROUP_TYPE_NAME", nullable = false)
    protected String groupTypeName;
    ....
    ...
}
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
@Table(name = "TABLE_REGION")
public class Region implements Auditable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "region_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "REGION_ID", sequenceName = "REGION_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "REGION_ID", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "REGION_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    ...
    ..
}
```

Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: You just posted the Entity classes, where is the logic to "read the new/updated content from the past 3 hours". And are implementing callback methods of EntityListeners.

Comment: @Venkat, I was able to create my first service using the below link danvega.dev/blog/2017/07/05/… @RequestMapping(value = "/batch/campus/delta", method = RequestMethod.GET) public Campus list() { return campusService.findAll(); } I am currently writing a job which runs every 3 hours and calls this rest service I am looking for an option how to get the latest content when I called the service findall gives me all results every-time

Comment: Ok. Hi @Sudheer, to fetch records which are updated/inserted in last 3 hours, you need to create a field in Entity class and then you need to write a query to fetch those records. For your reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date

Comment: @Venkat, thanks for the details, Sorry I have added it in the comment by mistake for the 3 hours, I have seen the query option mentioned in the link of my question. I have different tables and joining them using the joinColumn annotations via JPA api. 
The logic for combining the data is already present with the joincolumn, with query, i will be duplicating the same logic, in case if I need to add a new column or change some logic, I have to make the change in both the places. Is there any best practice or a common place where I can make the change to achieve this?